# TelegramBot user link text for markdown

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I use TelegramBotClient v.17.0.
I want to add link to telegram user with markdown, when edit the message text.

My text is

```
 var text = $"Profile [inline mention of a user](tg://user?id={userId})"
```

Then

```
_botClient.EditMessage(_monitoringTeamChatId,
                                   messageId: tgMessage.MessageId,
                                   text: text,
                                   parseMode: ParseMode.Markdown,
                                   inlineKeyboard: inlineKeyboard);
```

My link to user profile is now witn text "inline mention of a user".
How i can get own text "profile" for link?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $"Profile [Profile ](tg://user?id={userId})"
```

The text 'inline mention of a user' no needed.